# Rxjs chain to convert observable<File> to observable<string> (base64)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, dom-events, rxjs-observables

I have a working code to convert my File object to base64:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(myFile);
     reader.onload = () => {
         let resultStrOrArrayBuf = reader.result;
         if (!(resultStrOrArrayBuf instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
            ..do something with resultStrOrArrayBuf
         }
    };
```

However I do now have to integrate this part to an existing rxjs chain. In the chain I receive the File object and would like to go on with the base64 result of the conversion. However the conversion is done with the help of the `onload` event. Is there some way to convert this event to a new observable and pass this to the chain?

Comment: This is a [repo](https://github.com/EnricoPicci/observable-fs) where I have defined some wrapper functions to turn the standard callback-based `node.fs` public functions to Observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no out of the box method to convert this loaded event to rxjs observable. you will have to make your own operator.

```ts
export const dataUrlToObs = myFile => new Observable<string | ArrayBuffer>(subscriber => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(myFile);
  reader.onload = () => {subscriber.next(reader.result); subscriber.complete(); };
  reader.onerror = () => subscriber.error(reader.error);
  return () => reader.abort(); // cancel function in case you unsubscribe from the obs
}
```

it later can be used like this:

```ts
..chain
switchMap(myFile => dataUrlToObs(myFile)),
tap(resultStrOrArrayBuf => {
   if (!(resultStrOrArrayBuf instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
         ..do something with resultStrOrArrayBuf
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following helper function, which accepts a `Blob` as a parameter and return an `Observable<string>`:

```
function blobToBase64(blob: Blob): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>(observer => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onerror = observer.error;
      reader.onabort = observer.error;
      reader.onload = () => observer.next(reader.result as string);
      reader.onloadend = observer.complete;
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

      return {
        unsubscribe: reader.abort
      }
  })
}
```

**Usage:**

```
declare const fileObservable: Observable<File>;

fileObservable
  .pipe(switchMap(blobToBase64))
  .subscribe(base64 => console.log(base64))
```

Comment: I think you should use arrow function everywhere since you can get "this._complete is not a function" error because it doesn't run in the same scope.